# Create a third interface that uses the inherit interface implementation c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have 2 interfaces as you can see :

```
public interface i1
{
 void add(news a);
}
```

and

```
public interface i2
{
void add(file f);
}
```

These two interface has own implementation .I want to crate another interface called i3 that inherit both i1 and i2 and uses their implementation ?How can i do that?

```
public interface i3:i1,i2
{

}
```

In fact i want to get all methods inside i3 using i2,i1 implementation .because the implementation of i3 for that methods is same .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not understanding your question, but this compiles properly

```
public interface I1
{
    int One { get; set; }
}

public interface I2
{
    int Two { get; set; }
}

public interface I3 : I1, I2
{
    int Three { get; set; }
}

// Implementation of I3 (which inherits I1 and I2)
public class Foo : I3
{
    public int One { get; set; }
    public int Two { get; set; }
    public int Three { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't need a class . i need an third interface

Comment: @EhsanAkbar You have a third interface. `I3`

Comment: you know i am using wcf service .i want to integrate all my interface inside one interface and define the final interface inside wcf

Comment: @EhsanAkbar I'm not sure what your question about inheritance of `interface` has to do with WCF at all. Have a quick read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/

Answer (score 1):

Interface is for declaration not for implementation. Instead you should declare whatever you want in i3 and inherit all your interfaces in class

```
public interface i1
{
  int Add(int num1, num2);
}

public interface i2
{
 int Multiply(int num1, num2);
}

public interface i3
{
 int Divide(int num1, num2);
}

public class Mathematics: i1, i2, i3
{
  public int Add(int num1, int num2)
 {
   //Your implementation
 } 
 public int Multiply(int num1, int num2)
 {
   //Your implementation
 } 

 public int Divide(int num1, int num2)
 {
   //Your implementation
 }  
}
```

If inheriting interface by interface itself is intended like

`ICollection<T>`

interface does you can inherit like a class inherit interface.

```
public interface i1
{
  int Add(int num1, int num2);
}

public interface i2 
{
 int Multiply(int num1, num2);
}

public interface i3 : i1, i2
{
  int Divide(int num1, int num2);
}

public class Mathematics:  i3
{
  public int Add(int num1, int num2)
 {
   //Your implementation
 } 
 public int Multiply(int num1, int num2)
 {
   //Your implementation
 } 

 public int Divide(int num1, int num2)
 {
   //Your implementation
 }  
}
```

Thus, when you inherit i3 in a class you will get everything you have declared in i1, i2, and i3. While inheriting i1 will provide only i1 memebers similarly for i2.

Comment: I don't need a class . i need an third interface